# Django setting a ManyToMany field to the current value of another ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to set the value of my StudentMeeting model's current_courses ManyToManyField field to the value of my Student.course ManyToManyField so each meeting keeps a record of what courses the student was enrolled in at the time of the meeting.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Unrelated models omitted...

class Student(models.Model):
    """Model representing a student"""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Student first name.")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Student last name.")
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course, help_text="Select courses student is enrolled in.", blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        """String representing the Model object"""
        return self.last_name + ", " + self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detailed record for this student"""
        return reverse("checkin-student-detail", args=[str(self.id)])


class StudentMeeting(models.Model):
    """Model representing a check-in appointment"""

    instructor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, default='')
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, help_text="Student Name.", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    appointment_date = models.DateField("Date", default=timezone.now)
    attended_meeting = models.BooleanField()
    missing_work_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    narrative = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    current_courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        """String representing the Model object"""
        return str(self.appointment_date) + ": " + self.student.last_name + ", " + self.student.first_name


@receiver(post_save, sender=StudentMeeting)
def set_current_courses(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.current_courses.set(instance.student.course.all())
```

The vary last line is throwing errors. I'm not sure if I just have the syntax wrong or if I'm way off on the right way to do this...

Edit: I think I forgot to run migrations and reset the server after changing my models. Everything works as expected after reopening the project.

Comment: Can you share the error/full traceback? Is it not an option to just get a `StudentMeeting`'s courses from the student foreign key?

Comment: You can get the course from StudentMeeting.student.couse if I only need it now. The problem is I want to store what courses student were in at the time of the meeting since courses have end dates on top of students adding and dropping courses whenever. If my_student finished math1 so we remove it from his courses and add math2 all of the meetings from when he was in math1 will say math2 if we just get it off the student. I'll add he error message.